# Network is not auto-enabled after start up

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet

After normal system start no network is detected. If I plug off ethernet cable and insert usb wi-fi, no new device is detected either.

However if I run system in recovery mode and enable networking in recovery menu, the internet works fine. The problem is I must do it every single time I start my computer.

```
ifconfig
sudo lshw -C network
```

prints this: http://pastebin.com/wcJztG9R

In 2nd case I can see "*-network DISABLED". Tried to enable it in network menu, but nothing is detected.

Seems strange to me. I do not remember changing any config files or network settings. I just restarted my PC and network stopped working.

I use Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Comment: A lot of people have these problems these days: http://askubuntu.com/questions/772317/network-manager-crashes/772324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while system repaired itself. What goes around comes around.

Answer (score 0):

*[Note: if you don't have your WiFi adapter plugged in, omit the commands containing `wlan0`]*

After boot, try running these commands:

```
sudo su
service network-manager stop
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig wlan0 up
ifconfig eth0 up
service network-manager start
```

Comment: This did not work. After recovery it even disabled working network and did not re-enabled it.

Comment: @user138974 - Alright. After boot try running `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Tried it and got info about process running, but still no network connection. Do you think distro-upgrade may help and bring proper configuration?

Comment: @user138974 - I'd see if Software Updater has any updates for you first.